# Breakpoints rules won't apply in Material UI theme

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, themes

I'm writing a React application using Material UI. I have the following global theme file:

```js
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import createBreakepoints from '@material-ui/core/styles/createBreakpoints';
import '../../index.css';

const font = "'Ubuntu', sans-serif";
const breakpoints = createBreakepoints({});

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#3a2d96',
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#ff7b7d',
    },
    text: {
      primary: 'white',
      secondary: 'black',
    },
    grey: {
      A100: '#988d8b',
      A200: '#3f3f46',
    },
  },
  typography: {
    fontFamily: font,
    [breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      fontSize: 6,
    },
    [breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      fontSize: 4,
    },
  },
});

export default theme;
```

The breakpoints aren't applied.

I'm trying to change the `fontSize` property on the global theme file so that any typography component in my app will have this rule.

Comment: can you create a [sandbox] (https://codesandbox.io) of this issue. it'll be helpful

Comment: `fontSize` needs to be specified for specific variants (e.g. `body1`, `body2`).

Comment: @RyanCogswell, according to the documentation, there is a fontSize property on the typography object, and it can be changed (if I change it without the media queries it does work), so why not via media queries?

Comment: @barsh11 I assume you are referring to [this documentation](https://material-ui.com/customization/typography/#font-size). You'll see there that this variant-neutral `fontSize` isn't used directly, but rather it is used as [a multiplier](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.2/packages/material-ui/src/styles/createTypography.js#L44) for determining the variant-specific font sizes.

Comment: @RyanCogswell thank you, I will take a further look into it but I get your point.